# R knn forward stepwise feature selection starting with 2 variables

Tags: r, knn

I'm trying to do stepwise forward feature selection on a `knn` model.  I'm using the `FSelector` package and the `forward.search()` function.

The data set is ~ 400k rows by ~ 100 columns before feature elimination.

The problem is that the best performing feature doesn't have a lot of levels and thus there are a lot of ties causing the model to fail.

My question is this:

If I know what the best performing feature is, is there a way to start the forward.search() with 2 variables instead of one?

In other words if I have 5 variables.  The forward.search would go through them searching for the best one like :

```
depVar ~ var1
depVar ~ var2
depVar ~ var3
depVar ~ var4
depVar ~ var5
```

once the best one is determined (ie `var3`) the algo would do this:

```
depVar ~ var3 + var1
depVar ~ var3 + var2
depVar ~ var3 + var4
depVar ~ var3 + var5
```

and so on.  Is there a way to skip to the second step if I know the best performing single variable?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to change your `depVar` to the residuals from `depVar~ var3`? Then do the first forward selection method.

Comment: Since the argument of 
`forward.search()`
is a function that tells how important 
a subset of predictors is, 
you could just have it return 1 or 0
when there is only one predictor.